# ¿Cómo reemplazar y excluir letras de condicional de búsqueda en MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito hacer un query a una tabla `producto` donde existe una propiedad llamada `nombre` para buscar un nombre similar `LIKE`.

```
SELECT *
FROM producto
WHERE nombre LIKE '%Dulces%'
```

Pero ahora necesito a esto hacerle indiferente el uso de la `S` y de `Z`, es decir, si buscan `Dulcez` que aparezcan los resultados de la palabra `Dulces` y también los resultados de `Dulcez`. Asi mismo, si buscan la palabra `Dulces` deberán aparecer los resultados de `Dulces` y de `Dulcez`.

Al mismo problema tengo que hacer indiferente el uso de la leta `H`, es decir, si buscan `Aora` deben aparecer los resultados de `Ahora`.

Comment: Y que pasaria si buscan realmente un producto con la letra Z supongamos Taza? lo trasnformaria a tasa?

Comment: Gracias por la observación. Voy a corregir la pregunta para más detalles.

Comment: Claro y vemos que se puede hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mejor forma de hacerlo es dejar ambos, la cadena a buscar y los campos de la tabla de un solo formato, en este caso transformar todas las 's' en 'z' y eliminar todas las 'h' de ambos, para esto se puede usar `replace()` de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT *
FROM producto
WHERE replace(replace(nombre,'z','s'),'h','') LIKE replace(replace('%Dulces%','z','s'),'h','')
```

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero ¿cómo sería esto escalable si tienes mas escenarios donde requiere de la misma funcionalidad pero con combinaciones distintas?

Comment: @Aprendiz la verdad no se como podría hacerse mas escalable sin recurrir a una librería o crear un procedimiento, pero considero que el método es eficiente para encontrar los elementos que contengan la cadena, por ejemplo si uno de los resultados de `'%Dulcez%'` fuera `'Dulces Pequeños'`.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Esto resuelve perfecto mi problema.

Comment: @akko de nada, que tengas buen día.

Answer (score 3):

lo que intentas hacer es posible utilizando soundex,  busca lo que indicas de la siguiente forma:

```sql
SELECT * FROM producto WHERE nombre SOUNDS LIKE 'Dulcez' ;
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM producto WHERE nombre SOUNDS LIKE 'aora' ;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto me funciona para algunos casos de uso, pero no para cuando el nombre está compuesto de varias palabras `Dulces ricos`. Sólo me funcionó para cuando el nombre es de una sola palabra.